# Minimum number of relatively isolated nodes in a graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let G be a simple graph with $2n$ nodes, with each node having $m$ edges ($m$, $n$ are both unfixed integers).
Prove that there are at least $$k=\left\lceil \frac{2n-1}{m}\right \rceil$$
nodes that are not connected to each other (there is no edge between any of the two nodes).

I found this in a discrete math book  and I have no idea how to solve it. I would seriously appreciate some help.

Comment: $roof(x)$ means $\lceil x \rceil$?

Comment: Yes. I just don't know how to type that. @kimchi lover

Comment: And I suppose you mean $(2n - 1)/m$ and not $2n - 1/m$?

Comment: By the way, what does $m,n$ being "unfixed" mean?

Comment: It means they can be any chose number@Dániel G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use [Brook's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%27_theorem).

Solution:

> If $G$ is complete, then $k=1$ and the statement is trivial. Otherwise, by Brook's theorem the vertices of $G$ can be colored by $m$ colors such that each color class forms an independent set. One of these color classes must have size at least $\lceil2n/m\rceil \geq k$, as required.